# Как перенести каждую строку на новую?

Tags: php

У меня есть вот такой текст:

```
1.234.91.115:80 1.34.41.181:80 101.231.48.200:3128 104.128.82.180:9999
```

Как сделать, чтобы каждый ip-адрес был в новой строке? Перебирать каждый адрес не вариант.

Comment: перебирать скриптом тоже не вариант?

Comment: Если текст уже в строке то: `$string=str_replace(" ","\n",$string)` (если там по 1 пробелу разделитель)

Comment: Не получается(Я просто ноль в php). 
Можете сделать пример кода с этим текстом?

Comment: А зачем тогда именно php ? если вы под *nix то проще из командной строки `sed` В принципе для php вам ответ уже дали

Comment: PHP_EOL вставляйте

Answer (score 1):

Заменяйте пробел на `<br />`. Вот один из наиболее простых/эффективных вариантов:

```
$result = preg_replace("/ +/", '<br>', $ips);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pullIP = "ваши адреса строкой"; //или строка из файла

$IP = explode(" ", $pullIP);

foreach ($IP as $value) {
    echo trim($value)."<br>"; //выводим в браузер
}
```

Comment: Не выходит, все-равно в одну строку

Comment: изменил пример.

Comment: @user198445 А вы это куда выдаете ? В браузер что ли. браузер же переводы каретки не понимает если текст не в <pre>, заключайте его в <pre> или вместо переводов кареток <br>

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer `preg_replace("/ +/","<br>",$string)` как то попроще будет. И побыстрее

Comment: согласен, просто по мне так наглядней)

Comment: И возможно текст уже через \n  на самом деле ... тогда `preg_replace("/[ \r\n]+/","<br>",$string)`

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО, а теперь еще один вопрос. Как сделать что бы все выгружалось из текстового файла?

Comment: $pullIP = file_get_contents('ip.txt'); файл лежит в одной папке со скриптом

Comment: Ручной перебор в `foreach` для такой задачи избыточен!